# Azure Site Recovery replication policy

Tags: azure

Performing azure site recovery in South India region of azure data center.
My machines are replicated using the configuration server and agents through a Virtual Private Network tunnel between my on premise network and Azure . Now suppose after all the process is done.

Now One day my network bandwidth gets choked and my network team asks me to stop the replication and then continue the replication again when the proper bandwidth is available.

can i do that?? or i have to delete all the servers and then replicate them from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that (in short there's an ability to configure replication windows, when the traffic gets send over the wire), follow these articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-faq
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3056159